# Can a single gdb installation be configured to work with python 2 AND python 3?

Tags: python, gdb

I build and install various gdb installations. We currently build gdb with python 2 support via the "--with-python= setting, but now I have some requests for gdb to support a python 3 version as well.

I can do separate builds & installations - e.g. one gdb with python 2.7, another with python 3.4 etc.

I'd like to know if there is any way for a SINGLE build & installation of gdb to have both python 2 and python 3 support, rather than needing to double-up on the number of gdb installations

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is possible. GDB is a binary, dynamically linked with libpython. You can't dynamically link with both versions simultaneously, that's why you have to choose one of them. For example on my box GDB is linked with python 3:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/gdb | grep python
    libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 (0x00007f39f9c37000)
```